# Crystal Reports 8 connection string

Tags: mysql, crystal-reports-2008

I have installed Crystal Reports 2008 on my Windows PC at work.

We have an internal MySQL server which has data which we need to access. I have the IP address, port, user, password and database-name.

When I fire up Crystal Reports, and run the Report Creation wizard, it gave me a slew of ways to connect to various data sources, but not MySQL. I tried ODBC, but it asked for a connection string. How do you make a proper connection string for MySQL? Is ODBC even the right way to go?

How do I connect this thing to MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[connectionstrings.com](http://connectionstrings.com/) is an excellent resource for connection string examples.

Comment: I did an end-run by installing the MySQL connector and then adding an ODBC data source to my computer. Crystal Reports did it just fine.